# ColdFusion: get arguments of function which throws error in the onError-method of Application.cfc

Tags: coldfusion, user-defined-functions, coldfusion-9, application.cfc

I'm extending my errormanagement function which dumps a few scopes of variables and sends them via email to me. I'm using the onError-method in the Application.cfc for this case.

```
<CFDUMP var="#arguments.exception#" label="Error">
<CFDUMP var="#Application#" label="APPLICATION-Scope" />
<CFDUMP var="#form#" label="FORM-Scope">
<CFDUMP var="#url#" label="URL-Scope">
<CFDUMP var="#CGI#" label="CGI-Scope" />
<CFDUMP var="#session#" label="SESSION-Scope" />
<CFDUMP var="#variables#" label="VARIABLES-Scope" />
```

the onError has the exception as argument which I dump first in this example.... but how do I get the arguments of the function in which the error occured? For example if I call a UDF in my Application.cfc's onRequest-method like `<CFSET giveMeMyScripts("javascript-file-1","javascript-file-2") />` Is this possible to get `javascript-file-1` and `javascript-file-2`? Kind of super-arguments?

Thanks for any thoughts on this.

Comment: I take it you don't know the function where the error is occurring? If you know which method is throwing the error then you can wrap its code in a CFTRY, dump the `arguments` scope in your CFCATCH -- or perhaps copy that scope to the `request` scope and dump that in `onError()` as well -- then use CFRETHROW. I don't think the `onError()` method would have access to another method's `arguments` scope. Hope this helps.

Comment: you are right, I don't know which function is causing the exception (the errormanagement is used in many applications). Thanks for the cfrethrow hint - that's pretty useful for newer projects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but you may be able to just dump arguments. It might depend how many functions deep you are.

Generally if you dump all the scopes and the exception, you have all the bits of information you need.

We do almost exactly what your doing and dump every scope in the application.cfc

Comment: I think dumping `arguments` will only dump the `arguments` scope of `onError()`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can do this without setting up a specific error trap inside the function. But if you are simply *debugging* and need to get past the error, copy the arguments into the request scope temporarily and then dump the request scope.

Comment: It looks like he would have to do this to every method - he doesn't know which one is throwing the error.

Comment: yeah this is where the beauty of dependency injection loses a little shine sometimes :)